# LEFT JOIN in VBA not returning Null values

Tags: sql, vba, excel, ms-access

I have a VBA code in Excel which connects to an Access data base and I am doing a LEFT JOIN select.
When I execute this Select in Access, it returns the number of Null/Empty value and also those that are not null. But If I execute this same Select on VBA, the Null/Empty values do not return. How can I make to return the Null/Empty values in VBA execution?

Here is the select I am using:

```
SELECT COUNT(SP_Cod_Projeto) AS NumProjetos, CA_Nome_Categoria
FROM (TB_Projeto
LEFT JOIN TB_Selecao_Projetos ON TB_Selecao_Projetos.SP_Cod_Projeto = TB_Projeto.PJ_Cod)
LEFT JOIN TB_Categoria ON TB_Projeto.PJ_Categoria = TB_Categoria.CA_COD
GROUP BY CA_COD, CA_Nome_Categoria
ORDER BY COUNT(SP_Cod_Projeto) DESC, CA_Nome_Categoria
```

So again, for CA_Nome_Categoria that are Null/Empty is not returning when I execute it on VBA, but it returns when I execute on Access.

To explain the tables, I have projects registered on TB_Projeto which holds the Category code, the names of categories are in the TB_Categoria table. I have another table called TB_Selecao_Projetos which holds some of the project codes from TB_Projetos. So, what I need is to return the quantity of projects I have in TB_Selecao_Projetos by each category, but in the result I want the quantity of project and the name of the category related.

Thanks

Comment: Please qualify all your column names (by including the table alias) so we can understand the query.

Comment: I edited my post now explaning the SQL

Comment: [How to ask a good SQL question](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/271056/3820271). Sample data and expected result is much more useful than a textual description. Sample data != real data.

Comment: your problem is a SQL problem not a VBA problem. I havent yet run into an issue where my embedded sql via vba is incorrect due to VBA. you are either not providing sufficient code or are altering code. Please adjust

Comment: You wouldn't get any null values in this query, If there was no rows in the associated table, you would the `CA_Nome_Categoria` with a count of 0..